# how to install phalcon php on amazon linux

Tags: php, centos, phalcon, yum

I followed the phalcon documentation and added the repo to my system.

```
> curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
...
The repository is setup! You can now install packages.
```

But then when I continue to follow documentation:

```
> yum install php70u-phalcon
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No package php70u-phalcon available.
```

And searching for phalcon does not return anything:

```
> yum search phalcon
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Warning: No matches found for: phalcon
```

So where am I going wrong?

Comment: If there is no package available for Amazon AMI, you will need to compile it from source. https://docs.phalconphp.com/3.4/en/installation#installation-sources

Comment: Because they are not there, I thought that's why I have to add the packages like shown above?

Comment: I had to compile it from source in a similar situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Phalcon documentation install guide just doesn't work.
Believe or not it's easier to compile phalcon extension from scratch.

I have a cookbook that I always use when create a new EC2 instance and have to install phalcon extension:

**Installing php7.2 and some of its extensions**

```
amazon-linux-extras install php7.2 -y
yum install php-bcmath php-gd php-mbstring php-pecl-mcrypt php-mysqlnd php-opcache php-pdo php-pecl-igbinary php-pgsql php-process php-soap php-xml php-xmlrpc -y
```

**Installing some packages needed for compiling phalcon**

```
yum install php-devel gcc libtool pcre-devel re2c -y
cd /tmp
yum install git -y
```

**Installing phalcon 3.4.x since I'm not feeling 4.0 reliable enough**

```
git clone https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon
cd cphalcon/build
git checkout origin/3.4.x
```

**This code is just in case you don't have enough RAM**

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=5120
chmod 600 /var/swap.1
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

**Compiling phalcon. It may take several minutes**

```
sudo ./install
```

**Enabling phalcon extension**

```
echo "; Enable phalcon extension module
extension=phalcon.so" >> /etc/php.d/50-phalcon.ini
```

**Restarting services**

```
service httpd restart
service php-fpm restart
```

**Again, this commands are just if you don't have enough RAM**

```
/sbin/swapoff /var/swap.1
rm -rf /var/swap.1
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: For future readers, note Phalcon requires the PSR extension now.  
Please refer to https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/installation
As per this answer, on Amazon Linux, you'd then need `/etc/php.d/40-psr.ini` with the contents: `extension=psr.so`
Verify you see the "psr" extension in `php -m` then check for "phaclon" in there to make sure it's loaded. Once you see psr and phalcon loaded, go ahead and reload httpd and php-fpm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: using php 7.1 and phalcon 3.4.0

```
# Install PHP 7.1

yum install epel-release -y
yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm -y
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71
yum install php php-common php-opcache php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql php-mbstring php-pecl-zip php-imap php-fpm php-intl -y

# Install Phalcon3.4 

yum install php-devel pcre-devel gcc make -y
curl -LO https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/archive/v3.4.0.tar.gz 
tar xzf v3.4.0.tar.gz && cd cphalcon-3.4.0/build 
sh install
echo "extension=phalcon.so" > /etc/php.d/phalcon.ini
cd ../.. && rm -rf v3.4.0.tar.gz cphalcon-3.4.0
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: If you are use "remi-php71' repository, simple use the php-phalcon3 package ;)